# Tensorflow 1.0 : Retreive hidden state from restored RNN

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, restore

I'd like to restore an RNN and get the hidden state.

I do something like that to save the RNN:

```
loc="path/to/save/rnn"
with tf.variable_scope("lstm") as scope:
    outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(..)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path = saver.save(sess,loc)
```

Now I want to retreive `state`.

```
graph = tf.Graph()
sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
with graph.as_default():
      saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(loc + '.meta', clear_devices=True)
      saver.restore(sess, loc)
      state= ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `state` tensor to a graph [collection](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L3861), which is basically a key value store to track tensors, using [tf.add_to_collection](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.6/api_docs/python/tf/add_to_collection) and retrieve it later using [tf.get_collection](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_collection). For example:

```
loc="path/to/save/rnn"
with tf.variable_scope("lstm") as scope:
    outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(..)
    tf.add_to_collection('state', state)


graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
      saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(loc + '.meta', clear_devices=True)
      state = tf.get_collection('state')[0]  # Note: tf.get_collection returns a list.
```

Comment: It works thanks! But one must know that "state" can't be saved as a tuple and must be seperated into two objects before adding to collection. Then one must restore the two objects to build back the state tuple. Maybe you would edit your answer.